# Limit size of shared folder in Windows Server 2003 SP2

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2003

I have a machine with Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition, SP2. The hard-drive is in NTFS format. I am sharing a folder from this machine.

I would like to know if a limit exists for:

- the size of a shared folder
- how many files can exist in a shared folder

For example, I have this folder structure, where `Root_folder` is shared:

```
\Root_folder
    \Child_folder
```

I need to how to limit the size of `Child_folder`. (I don’t use File Server Resource Manager for quota managment.)

Answer (score 1):

> I need to how to limit the size of Child_folder. (I don’t use File
>   Server Resource Manager for quota managment.)

There is no way of doing this without using quotas that FSRM offers or buying a third party tool (there used to be several, but these days, most people just use Windows built in capabilities).

Is there a reason you don't want to use them?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size a single file on an NTFS volume can have is [16TB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Limitations).

No matter what arbitrary limit you assume to be the maximum number of files in a single folder (hint: It's actually 4,294,967,295), I'm pretty sure you'll hit your storage limit (or the NTFS volume size limit) way before that.

I don't know of any additional limitations that could be imposed by the SMB protocol.